# get value/SelectedValue from @Html.Editorfor on for loop

Tags: html, jquery, for-loop, editorfor

In the below code snippet, I want to get the value for "@Html.EditorFor" using Jquery. I have tried many ways to get. but I couldn't. Thank you for any inputs.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="tblEvents">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th class="col-md-6 Subheading-2">Event Name</th>
                     <th class="col-md-6 Subheading-2">Event Date</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 @for(int i=0;i<Model.ModelEvents.Count;i++)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-6">
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ModelEvents[i].NAME)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ModelEvents[i].ADDRESS)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ModelEvents[i].PINCODE)
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.ModelEvents[i].EVENTNAME,new SelectList(Model.Events,"Value","Text",Model.ModelEvents[i].EVENTNAME),new { @class = "form-control eventname", style = "max-width:300px" })
                                
                               
                             </td>
                            <td class="col-md-6">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModelEvents[i].EVENTDATE, new { @class = "text  form-control eventdate" })
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
         </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

---

give the control an id and as it's in a loop include "i" to ensure a unique ID

```
new { @class = "text form-control eventdate", id = "foo_" + i }
```

you can then use this id as a reference for jquery to find

This will match any input whose ID starts with "foo_" so will match "foo_0", "foo_1", "foo_2" ect

```
$('input[id^="foo_"]').).each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val())
});
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I have tried this as well. No Luck, the value becomes "undefined" only always.

Comment: Moreover its on for loop, which is little tricky to get the value

Comment: see an update to answer, you can set the id with the I from the loop to ensure its unique, then in a foreach loop on all elements matching that ID work with the value to do whatever you need to